# Dampen onChange trigger react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have an element that calls an onChange trigger, what is the best way to make it so that if the trigger is called multiple times in quick succession, that it will wait and only trigger the last one.

Ex, with a form field, you backspace then quickly input a new value, so from an initial value of `17`, you hit backspace and it calls onChange with a value of `1`, then quickly enter a new number so it calls it again right after with a value of `18`.

How can I have it wait like 250-500ms so it only calls with the value of `18`?

Comment: What you're looking for is probably something like [lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce). And then hook the "debounced" function onto your component's constructor, and bind that function to your input `onChange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use debounce, you can find many implementations like https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function